How do I actually call arbitrary binaries and access filesystem from a Snap-sourced package?
None of the recommendations and other answers actually work! So, I installed FreeCAD from Snap, as it has the latest release candidates and provides better look and feel than AppImage. A also like that Snap is integrated in the Software Center, while an AppImage is just a binary file somewhere on my filesystem, which I immediately forget about.
sudo snap install freecad --devmode --channel=candidate

Note that I cannot install it in the classic mode (--classic) because it is not build with this mode:
Warning: flag --classic ignored for strictly confined snap freecad

Checking the devmode installation:
$ sudo snap info --verbose freecad

…
notes:               
  private:           false
  confinement:       strict
  devmode:           true
  jailmode:          false
  trymode:           false
  enabled:           true
  broken:            false
  ignore-validation: false
…

So, it has a strict confinement, in accordance to the snapcraft.yml, but installed in devmode, which, according to the docs…

A special mode for snap creators and developers. A devmode snap runs as a strictly confined snap with full access to system resources, and produces debug output to identify unspecified interfaces. Installation requires the --devmode command line argument. Devmode snaps cannot be released to the stable channel, do not appear in search results, and do not automatically refresh.

That's what I need, because in FreeCAD I have a macro to slice the solid in a slicer for 3D printing. The exact content of the macro is not important, what's important however, that it does two things:

Makes an STL file from the selected solid and saves it to the /tmp
Calls a slicer (Cura) with the path of that STL from the previous step.

Here is the piece of code for 1:
file = f'/tmp/{mesh.Label}_{id}.stl'
print(f'Exporting {selected.Label} to {file}')
Mesh.export([mesh], file)

And here is 2:
subprocess.Popen(['/usr/bin/flatpak', 'run', 'com.ultimaker.cura', file])

Yes, Cura is installed from Flathub, but in general flatpak run com.ultimaker.cura works in my Terminal.
Executing the macro gives an error:
17:20:02  Exporting Cube to /tmp/Cube001_618c394b-5e90-4af2-9e57-8fae23708f9c.stl
17:20:02  pyException: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/siarhei_krukau/snap/freecad/common/Cura.FCMacro", line 31, in <module>
    subprocess.Popen(['/usr/bin/flatpak', 'run', 'com.ultimaker.cura', *files])
  File "/snap/freecad/1154/usr/lib/python3.10/subprocess.py", line 971, in __init__
    self._execute_child(args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds,
  File "/snap/freecad/1154/usr/lib/python3.10/subprocess.py", line 1863, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception_type(errno_num, err_msg, err_filename)
<class 'FileNotFoundError'>: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/bin/flatpak'

First, although it said "Exporting Cube to /tmp/Cube001_618c394b-5e90-4af2-9e57-8fae23708f9c.stl", the file is not there. Instead, it is located here: /tmp/snap-private-tmp/snap.freecad/tmp/Cube001_618c394b-5e90-4af2-9e57-8fae23708f9c.stl. That is a "private" /tmp for the FreeCAD snap. Obviously, Cura would not have access to it anyway, but I could probably overcome that and store the STL in my home dir.
However, it turns out that FreeCAD cannot "see" flatpak executable from /usr/bin. Neither from /bin or just plain flatpak -- I tried these as well. To quickly check the "view" that FreeCAD has on the filesystem, I run this in it's Python console:
>>> [f for f in os.listdir('/usr/bin') if f.startswith('fl')]
['flock']

However the same code in Terminal gives this:
>>> [f for f in os.listdir('/usr/bin') if f.startswith('fl')]
['flock', 'flatpak']

I also tried a trick of creating a small shell script in the snap's common directory (~/snap/freecad/common/cura.sh), to call Cura instead, and call that script from the Macro:
flatpak run com.ultimaker.cura "$@"

It didn't work either. Same problem.
So it turns out that neither FreeCAD has access to the /tmp directory, nor it has access to all the executables in /usr/bin, /bin, despite being installed in the devmode.
That's not what I expected from the devmode. How do I actully get rid of this restrictions?
